# How do I query for a post by custom field?

Tags: custom-field, query-posts, query

I have a custom field called "song-id" and I'd like to lookup a post by a song-id value. Can someone give me the code snippet for it?

(bonus: also looking for a code to use the permalink in the post to redirect to that page)

Answer (score 0):

```
$songQuery = new WP_Query('meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'song-id',
        'value' => 'song id value here',
        'compare' => '='
    )
));
```

You can use above code to query with custom field then use loop to get the contents.

Comment: If it's just one key then you can directly use `meta_key` and `meta_value_num`

Comment: yes but it's better to use meta_query i think

Comment: Indeed it is! ;)